# NullPointerException in retrieving data from Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve value from firebase Database and store it in list View but the app is getting closed.
Exception in logCat is Coming as

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                              at
>   com.example.dell.week11.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:60)

This is Main Activity

```
package com.example.dell.week11;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
DatabaseReference databasefaq;
List<Faq> faqList;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databasefaq= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FAQ");
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    faqList=new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databasefaq.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            faqList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot faqSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Faq faq=faqSnapshot.getValue(Faq.class);
                faqList.add(faq);

            }
            FaqList adapter=new FaqList(MainActivity.this,faqList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Next is CustomAdapter FaqList:

```
package com.example.dell.week11;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Dell on 4/7/2017.
*/
 public class FaqList extends ArrayAdapter<Faq> {
 private Activity context;
 List<Faq> faqList;

public FaqList(Activity context,List<Faq> faqList){

    super(context,R.layout.list_layout,faqList);
    this.context=context;
    this.faqList=faqList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null,true);

    TextView q=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.questiontv);
    TextView a=(TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.answertv);

    Faq faq=faqList.get(position);
    q.setText(faq.getFaqQuestion());
    a.setText(faq.getFaqAnswer());
    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

And this is Model class

```
package com.example.dell.week11;

 /**
 * Created by Dell on 4/5/2017.
*/
public class Faq {
String faqid,faqQuestion,faqAnswer;

public Faq() {
}

public Faq(String faqid, String faqQuestion, String faqAnswer) {
    this.faqid = faqid;
    this.faqQuestion = faqQuestion;
    this.faqAnswer = faqAnswer;
}

public String getFaqid() {
    return faqid;
}

public String getFaqQuestion() {
    return faqQuestion;
}

public String getFaqAnswer() {
    return faqAnswer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `setContentView` in your onCreate method.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43285533/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `setContentView(R.whatever)` before you can find any ids in it and ListView in your layout XML, must be defined as

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    databasefaq= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FAQ");
    setContentView(R.layout.xyz);   //you missed this line
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    faqList=new ArrayList<>();
}
```